# Ubuntu 18.04 drains battery very fast after wake up from a deep sleep

Tags: 18.04, suspend, dell, power-management, battery

I'm a happy owner of the Dell XPS 9570 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed (kernel 4.15.0-46, nouveau driver) and external keyboard + monitor. It works really well, and its battery life is also great... well, at least until wake up from suspend (deep sleep). Always after waking up, Ubuntu **drains my battery very fast**, and fans work louder than usual. Closing all running apps doesn't make any difference :/

It cannot be related to the hardware, because Windows 10 pre-installed on this laptop does not have such problem.

I've checked output of the `dmesg`, `top`, `powertop` commands and I haven't found anything unusual. CPU usage is very low. Also I've tried the Nvidia proprietary driver, but didn't help. Any tips what may be wrong?

Comment: Filed a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1882510  (It's a good idea to file bugs instead of/as well as questions when you hit issues.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer**: It turned out to be a problem somewhere between kernel 4.15 and the touchpad.

Disabling the touchpad solved the problem:

```
sudo rmmod hid_multitouch
```

This is an acceptable workaround for me, since most of the time I use an external mouse. In rare cases, when I don't have a mouse at hand, I solve the problem by disabling + enabling the touchpad after waking up:

```
sudo rmmod hid_multitouch
sudo modprobe hid_multitouch
```

**EDIT March 2020:** Some time ago, I've realized that a moment of using the touchpad, after resuming the laptop also solves the problem.

---

**Long answer**

The `top` command showed a low overall CPU usage (below 8%), but surprisingly the following command:

```
watch -n1 "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep \"^[c]pu MHz\""
```

revealed that all CPU cores were running at the **highest frequency** (~3.8 GHz)!, while I was expecting to see the lowest possible frequency (0.8 GHz) due to the idle state. The `sudo powertop` has proven that the high power consumption indeed was coming from the CPU.

So I came back to the results of the `top` command, watched it closely, and one process looked suspicious: **irq/51-SYNA2393**:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
21874 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   2.0  0.0   0:03.18 kworker/0:0
    1 root      20   0  225780   9392   6472 S   1.0  0.0   0:21.78 systemd
  513 root     -51   0       0      0      0 D   5.3  0.0   1:00.15 irq/51-SYNA2393
 2673 greg      20   0 4569240 205392  73916 S   1.0  0.6   1:54.94 gnome-shell
 ...
```

The `dmesg | grep SYNA` output:

```
[148428.423272] input: SYNA2393:00 06CB:7A13 Touchpad (...)
[148428.423893] hid-multitouch 0018:06CB:7A13.0001: input,hidraw1: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [SYNA2393:00 06CB:7A13] on i2c-SYNA2393:00
```

revealed that IRQ 51 comes from the laptop touchpad. That's how I found the culprit.

To be honest, I'm not sure it it's a bug inside Linux kernel, or simply my touchpad is not top-notch supported. When I'll try a newer Ubuntu version with newer kernel I'll update this post.

Comment: My touchpad driver on Debian, Linux 5.2.0, is called `i2c_hid`. Same problem, same solutions for now.

Comment: Unloading the `hid_mulittouch` driver did *NOT* work for me on a XPS 9570 running ubuntu 18.04.1 with  5.0.0-37-generic BUT what *did* work was doing:
`sudo rmmod i2c_hid`
`sudo modprobe i2c_hid`

as per this comment: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/263#note_147818